# Connect Windows-mobile 6.5 application to sqlite database on PC

Tags: sqlite, windows-ce, windows-mobile-6.5

I am writing a application in vb.net that runs on windows mobile ce device. I am trying to connect to a sqlite db that resides on a PC, the device will be docked to the PC and use windows mobile device centre to connect to the PC. I know how to connect to SQL Server or Express from a wince application but not a sqlite database. Please note I am not trying to connect to SQL Server CE but to sqlite. Thanks in advance.

Comment: SQLite is file based. Do you have access to the PC's files from the device?

Comment: let's say I could, are you suggesting that I copy it to the device then open it? or is it possible to open it from the location on the PC? The file could potentially be very large, so I would not want to copy it to the device. I would rather try and connect to it.

Answer (score 0):

sqlite is a file based SQL implemenation. Normally there is no way to directly access files on the PC when a device is connected via ActiveSync. You may creat a network share on the PC to enable access to the sqlite file via a network connection and then use the virtual ActiveSync network connection between the PC and the device to open and map the network share for the device.

You may also use the activesync partner ship and automatically sync files between PC and device to let ActiveSync sync the file from PC to \My Documents on the device and then use this 'local' sqlite file in your code.